# "Verified Type" Design Pattern

Tags: java, oop, terminology, dependent-type

I'm wondering if there is a name for the design pattern of wrapping up values into objects which restrict the values allowed inside them. In other words, these objects force more restriction on the type system.

Bonus question: are there libraries for these things so I don't have to build my own bug-ridden versions of them?

## Example: A Range Type

In an ideal world, we'd be able to express a range type as a dependent type. For example, a range type for Integers would be defined by an upper and lower bound. The values in this type would be any number that fits within the range. Because Java doesn't allow dependent types, for good reason I'm sure, we need to strike a compromise.

The range type in the following mixes type variables with the value variable. Subtyping allows us to specify types for specific ranges, like 0 to 100, which would be that of a percentage amount:

```
class Range{
  final private int _tLower;
  final private int _tUpper;
  final private int _value;

  protected Range(int lower, int upper, int value){
    _tLower = lower;
    _tUpper = upper;
    _value = value;
    verify();
  }

  private void verify(){
    if(_value <= _tUpper && _value >= _tLower){
      return;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Value " + _value + " out of bounds: [" + _tLower + ", " + _tUpper + "]");
  }

  int getValue(){ return _value;}
}

class PercentageInt extends Range{
  public PercentageInt(int value){
    super(0, 100, value);
  }
```

A Range type could be passed/returned to/from certain functions. A programmer, seeing the type, would immediate instead of passing raw Integer or int types.

## Motivation

The motivation for such a pattern is to separate verification from computation. By explicitly declaring these more restrictive types, other people using your code could see at a glance what the type of variables should be, and this would avoid them passing in the wrong values and breaking everything.

Other examples I've thought of aside from range would be:

- An inequality type, with two numbers, one less than (or equal) the other.
- A string regex type - it contains a string and a regex, to which that string must conform. Subtyping would fix the regex to something concrete.

Note: all such types would need to obey either a condition of immutability, or invariance under their "verification condition". E.g. if we'd modified the above Range type to allow the value to be changed by mutator functions, any such mutators had better keep the value within the same range.

## Formal Alternatives - And Why They're Impractical

- [JML (Java modelling language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Modeling_Language). This allows you to annotate methods with pre and post conditions in a Hoare logic style. Ho
- [Howard-Curry correspondence in Java](https://github.com/zhangzhi-ksu/Curry-Howard-Isomorphism-In-Java). Like JML, this seems too "heavy" to be of practical worth. It is up to the programmer to construct the proofs that premise(s) imply conclusion, making coding a lot more complicated. On top of that, it means, without special modification of the javac or introducing an external tool like JML, that proof objects need to be carried around in memory at runtime. This would be a performance nightmare.

Comment: Actually on second thought - the range type shouldn't really store the bounds as variables. It's wasteful to the runtime memory. verify() should probably be stored as a lambda function associated with all objects of some subtype, meaning we only need to store the bounds in memory once per subtype. But this is just a performance tweak. The usage is the same.

Comment: (That's validation rather than verification. Also it should be in the order: copy (if necessary), validate (a.k.a. check) then use. The posted code has the validation after the use (assignment to fields). You've tagged as dependent-type which would have the values as parameters to the type: `Range<0, 100> aPercentage; Range<0, n> aBoundPositive;` (not legal Java).)

Comment: Here is a list of validation frameworks for java. Is it what you are looking for? http://java-source.net/open-source/validation

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Agreed that the validation should come first. I actually intentionally tagged this with dependent-type. On reflection, I guess what I'm trying to do here is to "flatten" the type parameters of a dependent type in with the value object, precisely because Java won't let me insert them into the type definition. Of course what I sketched can never have the same power as dependent types, but I was hoping to gain at least some of the advantages.

Comment: @Ruslan I had a look at the link. It got me thinking. The standard practice in Java seems to be: define your objects built up from primitive types, then define validation logic elsewhere, and call your validation logic at certain points in your application e.g. after data is read from the UI. This is certainly better than mixing validation logic with class data concerns, which does overlap with the theme of the question. However, I was looking for something a bit more low level- immutable types whose objects are validated exactly once at creation and thereafter can be trusted as valid.

Comment: @Ruslan- Perhaps my idea is a little impractical. I'm going to try it out and see if it's worth it. Perhaps all the overhead of creating these immutable objects is more effort than it's worth vs. just accepting the primitives and validating/testing thoroughly.